# Centre 2 images under 3 images with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

[My Site](http://www.gregorydanelian.comule.com)

On this website under the CURRENTLY READING... section there are 5 images. 3 on the top row are 2 underneath. I am happy with the way the 3 images sit using the `col-lg-4`

However I want the bottom two images to sit underneath centred, like so:

```
           □       □       □
               □       □
```

I have tried using margins on the bottom two images after applying `span6` but this affects the responsive positioning on browser resize.

How can I get the bottom two images to sit neatly centred without compromising responsivity?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, using both `col-sm-x` and `col-sm-offset-x` :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x150/2ecc71/fff" class="center-block">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x150/3498db/fff" class="center-block">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x150/e74c3c/fff" class="center-block">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x150/e67e22/fff" class="center-block">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/110x150/9b59b6/fff" class="center-block">
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/117237)

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Works just perfect. How did you learn col-sm-4, what is the best resource to understand Bootstrap grids/classes? I could not find col-sm-4 on their grid reference site.

Comment: @Danelian for the 2 images row, why not use col-sm-6?